# getting div content from different page DomDocument

Tags: php, html

I'm facing some issue with the use of DomDocument. 
I would like to grab the content in a div from test.php and put it into a form value in test2.php and i'm getting this error

> DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity

test.php

```
<?php 
    include_once "connect_db.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM client";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div id='drag' class='block' value='". $row["custNo"]."';>";
        echo "<div id='custNo'>Client ID: " . $row["custNo"]. "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
       }
    } else {
            echo "0 results";
            }
   mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

test2.php

```
<form class="form" action="#" id="siteVisitForm" method="post">
        <h3>Site Visit Date</h3>
        <label>Client ID: <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="clientID" name="clientID" value="<?php                                                                           
                                                                        $doc = new DomDocument;
                                                                        $doc->validateOnParse = true;
                                                                        $doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('hello.php'));
                                                                        var_dump($doc->getElementById('custNo'));?>"/>
        <label>Visit date: <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="visitDate" name="visitDate"/>
        <label>Comment:</label>
            <textarea id="custComment" name="custComment" placeholder="comment......."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" name="submit"/>
        <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

May I know how can i go about doing it?

Comment: To get html from that file, php will have to run it first. Loading it from its url might get you that result.

Comment: You are trying to parse PHP as if it would be HTML. Obviously this isn't possible.

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy since test2.php is using DOM to extract the contents of hello.php but your example code refers to a file named test.php.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer so is there any possible way which I can go around doing this?

Comment: Look at Sharon's answer. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the content of the target file into the second, assuming that the target file is hello.php and this file exists on the same domain as test2.php, using the HTTP protocol.  If you were to neglect indicating that protocol when accessing the file, then you will succeed in only retrieving PHP that requires parsing, i.e. `echo 'hello!';`.  The technique to access the target file as a URL is as follows:

file: hello.php

```
<?php

 echo 'hello!';

?>
```

file: test2.php

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$url = 'http://www.example.com/hello.php';
$contents = file_get_contents( $url );
$doc->loadHtml( $contents );
echo $doc->saveHTML(); // hello!
```

In this solution, the contents of hello.php will be returned as as HTML automatically b/c that's the way PHP works with the HTTP protocol.  So, $contents can easily be passed to the loadHTML method.

Note: this technique is advisable only where the files come from the same domain, although it might impact the webserver's performance.  If they come from different domains, the technique is inadvisable unless you're the owner of both, to avoid security problems.  To be extra safe one could pass the result of file_get_contents() to htmlentities() to avoid potential XSS problems.

Comment: @Emil the code in the test2.php file of the OP  gets the actual PHP code of file hello.php instead of a parsed result in HTML.